# Scrambled class name passed to spl_autoload_call via call_user_func

Tags: php, spl-autoload-call

I have discovered interesting behaviour of php while calling different classes dynamically.
For some reason class name get scrambled and its look like slice of hashed string.

here is example of php code I'm trying to execute:

```
call_user_func(array('app_event', 'arrayItems'));
```

Here is backtrace of this event:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [function] => autoLoader
        [class] => init
        [type] => ::
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => j7ltlqmoy
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [function] => spl_autoload_call
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => j7ltlqmoy
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [file] => /site/class.app.php
        [line] => 107
        [function] => call_user_func
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => app_event
                        [1] => arrayItems
                    )

            )

    )
 ...
 );
```

Can anybody explain what em I doing wrong and what can cause sting **app_event** to be translated in to **j7ltlqmoy**?

**UPDATE**
Script does work on all other classes and throws this weird text only when requested method is not implemented. I have managed to make my application work, however it still does not explain why does it scramble names instead of throwing error?

**UPDATE 2**
This event also occurs (tested on PHP 5.3.10) when you are trying to call method statically and static property is not declared. It can be fixed by declaring method static.

**UPDATE 3**
As mentioned in comment to my [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61766), this issue is caused by **Zend Guard Loader**

Comment: Can you give a short script with which we can try to reproduce this?

Comment: Do a grep for the string `j7ltlqmoy` over all your source files.  It may be that there's a dependency on that class or that somewhere it's doing an `class_exists()` call...

Comment: Reproducing script or it didn't happen :p

Comment: I've seen this happen too. did you find the reason for this?

Comment: it seems to happen when you are trying to call method that is not declared as static

Comment: Please add your solution (UPDATE3) as an answer below and accept it. This will make this site better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment to my [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61766), this issue is caused by **Zend Guard Loader**